# Is it semantically valid to wrap all page's tags inside the form tag - ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, semantics, semantic-markup, runatserver

I am not new to ASP.net. Actually, I am not even learning it. But, I was recently evaluating some Web sites and saw that awful `<form runat="server" ..>` that wraps the whole page and contains all other tags. The question: Is that valid HTML? It is 2012 and talks about semantic Web, accessible Web, etc. is hot. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is syntax-wise valid HTML. But I agree it's a bit 'outdated' a form and some hidden fields, etc. as ViewState. 
Also it can be quite cumbersome to work when you want to use more forms on the page (using JQuery f.i.).

Take a look at ASP.Net MVC, it solves the problem. You have full control over the HTML and does not need a form tag around the page. It does not use asp.net server controls.

Comment: I agree. MVC is the way forward. That said, every WebForms site i've built in the last couple of years I haven't used any of the ASP.NET controls apert from PlaceHolder and Literal.

Answer (score 1):

The [the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-form-element.html#the-form-element) isn't too restrictive and allows most elements to nest within a form, but does state

> The form element represents a collection of form-associated elements,
>   some of which can represent editable values that can be submitted to a
>   server for processing.

So it would seem to me that if the element isn't form-associated, it shouldn't really be there.

Comment: that is exactly what I thought too. every element has a specific meaning and that meaning must be respected. It is good though to see what the Web community thinks of it, and until now, I am positive with your answer and Rody's one.